# How do I reassemble mdadm array with both drives available?

Tags: arch-linux, configuration, mdadm, mirror

I need to re-instate an RAID 1 (mirror) array. I have both drives and mdadm tells me the following about them:

```
$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb1
[sudo] password for pi: 
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : c3178bbd:a7547105:dca0fc2a:4c137310
           Name : raspi:0
  Creation Time : Sun Feb 16 09:29:07 2020
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 240218112 (114.54 GiB 122.99 GB)
     Array Size : 120109056 (114.54 GiB 122.99 GB)
    Data Offset : 133120 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=133040 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 012f89b4:c8b76c0e:8ae8fb78:52cc8175

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Fri Jul 17 22:20:33 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : a3b8e3db - correct
         Events : 20895


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
[pi@alarm ~]$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : c3178bbd:a7547105:dca0fc2a:4c137310
           Name : raspi:0
  Creation Time : Sun Feb 16 09:29:07 2020
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 240218112 (114.54 GiB 122.99 GB)
     Array Size : 120109056 (114.54 GiB 122.99 GB)
    Data Offset : 133120 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=133040 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : baef96f5:8750ba2b:892f40a7:3ecc2b38

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Fri Jul 17 22:20:33 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : f302843f - correct
         Events : 20895


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

How do I recreate the array to mount the /dev/md0 (?) and get access to all the files on the drives?
The Array state says `AA` even though there is currently no array:

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    1 119.3G  0 disk 
`-sda1        8:1    1 114.6G  0 part 
sdb           8:16   1 114.6G  0 disk 
`-sdb1        8:17   1 114.6G  0 part 
mmcblk0     179:0    0  29.8G  0 disk 
|-mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   121M  0 part /boot
`-mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  29.7G  0 part /
```

Oh and:

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : 
unused devices: <none>
```

Which is active device 0 vs 1 when calling `mdadm --create`?

**UPDATE**

`sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1` gave me:

```
$ sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
[sudo] password for pi: 
mdadm: /dev/sda1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 is busy - skipping
```

and it looked like nothing happened but this shows that something did happen:

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    1 119.3G  0 disk  
`-sda1        8:1    1 114.6G  0 part  
  `-md0       9:0    0 114.6G  0 raid1 
sdb           8:16   1 114.6G  0 disk  
`-sdb1        8:17   1 114.6G  0 part  
  `-md0       9:0    0 114.6G  0 raid1 
mmcblk0     179:0    0  29.8G  0 disk  
|-mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   121M  0 part  /boot
`-mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  29.7G  0 part  /
$ cat /proc/mdstat               
Personalities : [raid1] 
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[2]
      120109056 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

Ipon whixch I was able to succesfully mount my array `/dev/md0`

and I executed `sudo mdadm --detail --scan | sudo tee -a /etc/mdadm.conf` in order to store the current array configuration to my mdadm.conf file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
```

Devices get their indices based on the order of create, it's purely ordinal